# Переписать в другой массив все элементы, которые находятся между максимальным и минимальным значением

Tags: c++, массивы

чтото не получается в конце. пустые элементы заполнить 0
нужно чтобы например есть массив {4,5,4,3,55,7,8,1,5,6}  в другом массиве должно отобразить {0,0,0,0,55,7,8,1,0,0}

```
#include <iostream>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ukr");
    srand(time(NULL));
    const int n = 10;
    bool change = true;
    int arr[n], arr2[n], m = 0, m2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 100;
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    int  min = arr[9], max = arr[9];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j]) 
                if(arr[i] > max) {
                    m = i;
                    max = arr[i];
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int z = 0; z < n; z++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (arr[z] < arr[j])
                if(arr[z] < min) {
                    m2 = z;
//                  cout << z << " ";
                    min = arr[z];
            }

        }
    }
    cout << endl << m2 << " " << m << endl;

    if (m > m2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (i <= m) {
                arr2[i] = arr[m];
                m++;
            }
            if (i > m2) {
                arr2[i] = 0;

            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << arr2[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

знаю что там в конце неправильно. помогите, а то уже незнаю что делать

Comment: Если например два одинаковых элемента с максимальным значением, например `{4,1,4,3,55,7,8,55,5,6}` то до какого из двух значений `55` нужна выборка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слишком много кода для такой простой задачи.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
// <algorithm> for c++98

using namespace std;


void make_array(int n, int src[], int dest[]) {
    int min_i = 0, max_i = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) { // находим индексы 1-ого min и последнего max элементов
        if (src[i] >= src[max_i]) max_i = i;
        if (src[i] < src[min_i]) min_i = i;
    }
    if (min_i > max_i) std::swap<int>(min_i, max_i);
/*
        То же самое, что и строчкой выше (можно убрать #include <utility>)
        if (min_i > max_i) {
            int tmp = min_i; min_i = max_i; max_i = tmp;
        }
*/

    for (int i=0; i<min_i; ++i) dest[i] = 0;
    for (int i=min_i; i<=max_i; ++i) dest[i] = src[i];
    for (int i=max_i+1; i<n; ++i) dest[i] = 0;
}


int main()
{
    int a[12] {-1, -2, -11, -2, 3, 5, 1, -1, -1, 1, -2, -1};
    int b[12];
    make_array(12, a, b);
    for (int i=0; i<12; ++i) cout << b[i] << ' ';
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: мне без функций нужно и без библиотек, только 1.5мес обучения

Comment: @tkachuk т.е. за 1.5мес обучения Вы не знаете, что такое функция? Нужно ли такое обучение?... Просто вставьте код из `make_array` в `main`. Вместо `swap` вручную поменяйте местами `min_i` и `max_i`. Тогда `<utility>` не нужно.

Comment: нас позже по библиотекам таскать будут

Answer (score 1):

Можно ничего не заполнять. Сделать сразу второй массив с нулями, а потом записать поверх нулей нужные значения.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
int main(){
    const int size = 10;
    int arr1[10] = {4,5,4,3,55,7,8,1,5,6};
    int arr2[10] = {0};

    int *min = std::min_element(arr1, arr1 + size); 
    int *max = std::max_element(arr1, arr1 + size); 

    int *begin1 = std::min(min, max);
    int *end1 = std::max(min, max) + 1;
    int *begin2 = arr2 + (begin1 - arr1);
    std::copy(begin1, end1, begin2);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        std::cout << arr2[i] << ",";
    }
}
```

Comment: Не знаю, насколько это нужно автору вопроса, но здесь кажется не учитываются повторы значений. Вернее учитываются, но используется первое вхождение и для максимального и для минимального элемента (не ясно, подходит ли это под задачу автора или нет).